# How can i fix X-cart product page ? Product page is blank

Tags: x-cart

I have x-cart site which is running from 4 years and suddenly product page is not working. we have not done any changes.

```
X-Cart DB Version: 4.1.9 GOLD
```

product page url : https://www.test.com/product.php?productid=40&cat=0&page=1&featured

I can see bellow error in log file `"x-errors_php-190521.php"`

PHP Fatal error:

```
Call to undefined function func_get_categories_list() in public_html/include/common.php on line 76

if (
                !isset($cat)
                || $config['Appearance']['root_categories'] == 'Y'
            ) {

            $categories = func_get_categories_list(0, false);

        } else {

Line No 76: =>>>            $categories = func_get_categories_list($cat, false);

        }
```

so help us to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to add the

```
x_load('category');
```

in the include/common.php right after the

```
case 'C':
```

line

2) Try to compare your product.php with the default one and localize the problem.

3) Try to compare your include/common.php with the default one and localize the problem.

4) Try to compare your include/categories.php with the default one and localize the problem.

5) Try to move `x_load('category');` before the code `switch ($current_area) {`

6) Try to add the code `include_once $xcart_dir . '/include/func/func.category.php';` before the code `switch ($current_area) {`

**Key notes:**

- include/common.php was added in X-Cart 4.4.0
- The func_get_categories_list function is defined in
  include/categories.php file in X-Cart 4.1.9
- The func_get_categories_list function is defined in
  include/func/func.category.php file in X-Cart 4.4.0
- It will be helpful to define the exact version of your files for that compare 
  files like include/func/func.core.php cart.php include/func/func.category.php include/func/func.order.php with the default ones.

Comment: Thanks , I have checked in version file which is in root folder in that x-cart Version 4.1.9 and in include/common.php file there is already "x_load('category');" code is available

Comment: Do you have the file  include/func/func.category.php ?

Comment: yes i have this file in /public_html/include/func/ func.category.php file